# Why .9.png in Eclipse/device not looks like in draw9patch.exe?

Tags: android, nine-patch

I create **combobox_normal_m.9.png** in **draw9patch.exe**. It looks very good in draw9patch.exe, but in Eclipse/device it's not so clear. Why edges are blurred?

**from layout:**

```
<Button
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/selector_cbutton_m" />
```

**from selector:**

```
<item 
    android:drawable="@drawable/combobox_normal_m"
    android:state_selected="false"
    android:state_pressed="false"/>
```

[image][image]

Comment: Because Eclipse PNG renderer sucks? :)

Comment: I've recently ran into this same thing.  I had a background that had a top and bottom 1px border.  I placed my "patches" on the vertical scaling of the image so they were 1px below/above the top/bottom borders.  For some reason, this cause the borders to also scale, which they shouldn't.  I was able to resolve this by placing the "patches" for the vertical scaling 2px above/below the top/bottom borders.  See if that helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've inverted the top and bottom 9 patch data. The top 1 pixel defines the area that can be stretched. The bottom 1 pixel defines the area that can be covered with content. Unless, I guess, you intended there to be a buffer between the right edge of the text and the vertical separator. I could be misunderstanding what you are trying to do.

You will also notice that you still have to create versions of the 9 patch for different densities if there are non-scalable features that you want to look right at the different pixel densities. In eclipse you are also seeing a enlarged (typically) version of the screen resolution so it may not be representative of the device.